# If the number of elements is up to 30000, will the program overflow the stack?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I am working with a large array, about 14400 elements.

This is my quickSort function:

```
void quickSort(slist_struct a[], int l, int h)
{
    if (l >= h) return;
    slist_struct pivot = a[(l + h) / 2];
    int i = l, j = h;
    while (i < j)
    {
        while (a[i].data > pivot.data) i++;
        while (a[j].data < pivot.data) j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            if (i < j) swap(a[i], a[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    quickSort(a, l, j);
    quickSort(a, i, h);
}
```

The program works well.

If the number of elements is up to 30000, will the program overflow the stack? Thanks.

Comment: It will depend on the size of the stack.

Comment: maybe. maybe not. Depends on your environment.

Comment: If you want to reduce stack consumption, I suggest getting rid of the local `struct` variable `pivot`, it is not necessary at all. You can replace it by a pointer or use `a[...]` directly

Comment: Unless your goal is to learn how to implement/optimize the quicksort algorithm I suggest to use the [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) standard function

Comment: If you want to analyze the stack usage of your function, well, then you need to analyze it.  What's the average recursion depth?  It should be O(log(n)) where n is array length.  What's the worst case?  If you end up with the worst possible pivot every time, the pivot will be the smallest (or largest) element, in which case the recursion depth will be O(n), and in fact it will be n.  So it depends on the array size, and also on whether you get extremely unlucky.

Comment: If you really want an in-place sort algorithm that doesn't consume stack, implement heapsort.  It tends to be slower than quicksort on average, but it has better worst-case performance.

Comment: As an exercise, it is not hard to rewrite quicksort without recursion using a heap-allocated state buffer.

Comment: Or, you could modify the function to only recurse on the smaller of the two parts and loop on the other, reducing the worst-case call depth to, I believe, log(n).

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
    while (i <= j)             /* was while (i < j) */
```

Answer (score 0):

The program may not overflow the stack.if it happen,  use a queue data structure instead. Firstly, let the queue be empty, let's call the number of elements you want to sort is N.The first element of the queue contains 1,N (queue[0].L = 1;  queue[0].R = n) .Now use your function to sort from (queue[0].L..queue[0].R) but change 
quickSort(a, l, j);
quickSort(a, i, h); 
to something likes this
queue.push(i,h);
queue.push(l,j);
queue.pop();
repeat this until the queue is empty 
do u need the full code?